Prove that the minimal and the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator are the same
Suppose $V$ is an $n$ dimensional vector space over a field $F,$ and $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be an ordered basis. Let $T:V\to V$ be the linear operator such that $T(v_1)=v_2, T(v_2)=v_3,...,T(v_{n-1})=v_n.$ Prove that the minimal and the characteristic polynomial of $T$ are the same.
I tried solving the problem as follows:
The minimal polynomial $f(t)$ of $T$ is the non-zero polynomial having the least positive degree such that $f(T)=T_0.$
We claim that $\deg f\geq n.$
For if, $\exists g(t)\in P(F)$ and $\deg g=k<n$ such that $g(T)=T_0$ then we can say that $g(t)=0.$
This can be easily verified by first assuming  $g(t)=a_kx^k+\cdots +a_0.$ Now, $$g(T)=T_0\implies g(T)(v_1)=T_0(v_1)=a_kT^k(v_1)+\cdots +a_0v_1=a_kv_k+\cdots +a_0v_1,$$ (, we have used the fact that $T^i(v_1)=v_i,1\leq i\leq n-1$). Now,  as $\{v_1,...,v_k\}\subseteq B$ and $B$ is linearly independent subset of $V$ so, $a_0=\cdots=a_k=0.$ This proves that $g(t)=0$, i.e a zero polynomial.
So, if $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ we must have $\deg f\geq n.$
Now, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ has degree $n$, and since the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$ so, we must have, $\deg f=n.$
Also, we must note that, $f(t)$ is a monic polynomial.

I am stuck at this step. If the characteristic polynomial $g(t)$ of $T$ is a monic polynomial then I can easily conclude that $f(t)=g(t)$ and the problem would be solved. But I can't seem to find a way to show that $g$ is a monic polynomial. Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

@TheoBendit Why so? I mean I don't get how are they related.

The minimal polynomial is usually defined as the monic polynomial with least degree that nullify $T$...

@Exodd Yes and?

low dimension:  let $$ M  = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & a \
1 & b \
\end{array}
\right)
$$  Write out  $$ M^2  = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & ab \
b & a+b^2 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$   and look for $M^2 =  xM + yI.$  It turns out there is exactly one solution, $M^2 =  bM + aI.$   or $M^2 - bM - aI=0$  If there were some other $(x,y)$  pair that worked, the difference would be a nonzero polynomial of lower degree,  some $(b-x)M + (a-y)I $   to give a different minimal polynomial. Not possible, the characteristic polynomial is also minimal.

Same little calculation $$ M = \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & a \
1 & 0 & b \
0 & 1 & c \
\end{array}
\right)
$$ Carefully write out $M^2$ and $M^3$   and then solve $M^3 = x M^2 + y M + z I.$  Again, just one $(x,y,z)$ triple. Please do that much

Also the characteristic polynomial is always monic

@ThomasFinley Sorry, I didn't read it properly last night.
